# Error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1776,1,2) (3896,1,2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

Im new to python and Im trying to write a code that extracts the contours from an image and sorts them in terms ascending order of length of elements in the list of contours. When I use sort() or list.sort(), I get an error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1776,1,2) (3896,1,2) 
How could I fix this?
This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLgSU.jpg)  I am using.

The error message I got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/dehaoliu/opencv_test/Engineering drawings/example.py", line 19, in <module>
    contours.sort()
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1776,1,2) (3896,1,2)
```

Below is the shortened code that produces the error:

```
import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from math import sqrt

name='20_right_5-1'
img = cv2.imread(name+'.JPG')
im = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(name+"_dilation.jpg", closing)
im = cv2.imread(name+'_dilation.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray,(5,5),0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.namedWindow("Contours")
cv2.imshow("Contours", im)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite(name+"_contour.jpg", im)
print "this is contours"
print contours
print type(contours)
contours.sort()
```

Comment: It's easy to _make the error go away_, it's less easy to make sure that the result is what you want it to be. Do you understand what those dimensions are in the error, and what size your expected result should be?

Comment: I believe they are the dimensions of the first and second elements in the list

Comment: Sorry If this is a dumb question. I have no prior experience with python and I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: Yes, but what is their purpose? My point is that I can tell you how to make the dimensions such that they broadcast, the result will probably have a shape of `(1776,3896,1,2)`, for instance. But whether this makes any sense is another matter, for which you should understand what's going on and what you exactly want to do.

Comment: I don't think I understand what their purpose is. Could you please explain? What I want to do is; however, to sort the list in terms of the length of each array so I can extract them later i.e the longest contour or the shortest contour

Comment: No, I can't because your question doesn't contain a [MCVE], instead it contains a huge wall of code. We're also missing a proper error message complete with line numbers. I'm fairly sure that your broadcasting error isn't coming from the `.sort()` line, but somewhere before.

Comment: I shortened the code and I also uploaded the image I am using. Maybe this is better. I apologize, Im fairly new to stack overflow. Im not familiar with the proper way to ask a question here, but thank you for letting me know.

Comment: In that case please also read [ask], and add your precise error message to the question :)

Comment: I just added the error message. I really appreciate you telling me about this. Thanks!

Comment: I could figure out your problem, and good job making the problem more minimal as a first step, but note that your current version doesn't run because some variables (such as `closing`) are missing. Next time please paste your example code separately and make sure it runs in a self-contained manner :) And sorry, you were perfectly right, the error indeed came from the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both your original question and your shortened version contain some errors which make reproducing your problem a bit difficult. Furthermore, you seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary things (such as importing math, Image, matplotlib, scipy etc without using them, or saving images only to read them back again in another name).

Anyway, the core of your question can be answered easily. Your `contours`, as returned from `cv2.findContours` look something like this:

```
>>> type(contours)
list
>>> len(contours)
15
>>> type(contours[0])
numpy.ndarray
>>> print(contours[0].shape)
(3888, 1, 2)
```

I.e. each of your 15 contours is a 3d numpy array with shape `(N,1,2)`. The singleton dimension aside, you essentially have `N*2` points in a matrix: `N` pairs of integers, i.e. `N` pairs of `x,y` image coordinates that trace the given contour on the image.

Now, when you're trying to sort this list-of-arrays, python tries to compare two elements, such as

```
contours[0] < contours[1]
```

But numpy arrays are compared *elementwise*, with so-called broadcasting used when the arrays have singleton dimensions in certain places. This implies the following behaviour:

```
>>> np.random.rand(2,3) < np.random.rand(1,3)
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.random.rand(2,3) < np.random.rand(4,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (4,3)
```

That is, arrays of *compatible* shape (such as `(2,3)` and `(1,3)`) are effectively expanded along singleton dimensions and comparison is done element by element. If the two shapes don't match (such as in the case of `(1776,1,2)` and `(3896,1,2)`), you get an error. But this is not what you want to do in the first place!

What you want to do is clearly expressed in your question: sort the contours according to length in ascending order. Great! We can still use `contours.sort` (or `sorted()` if we want a copy), but we need to tell `sort` *what to sort by*. In our case, it needs to *sort by length of the contour*. What is the lenght of the contour? For each contour `contour`, it is the size of its first dimension, i.e. `contour.shape[0]`.

The bottom line is that you need to pass a key function to `.sort` that allows you to sort by contour length, leading to comparison of integers (rather than arrays):

```
>>> [contour.shape[0] for contour in contours]
[3888, 1775, 1044, 1508, 255, 95, 233, 330, 310, 177, 155, 592, 506, 1044, 663]
>>> contours.sort(key=lambda contour: contour.shape[0])
>>> [contour.shape[0] for contour in contours]
[95, 155, 177, 233, 255, 310, 330, 506, 592, 663, 1044, 1044, 1508, 1775, 3888]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes so much sense now. I guess my inability to understand the error was due to my lack of familiarity with python and what respective lines of code were doing, but thank you for helping me understand it better :)

Comment: @Alizay I'm glad I could help. In case you have the time, learning native python itself helps a _lot_ if you want to use frameworks built on top. Anyway, if the above indeed solved your problem, please consider [marking my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).